# Django - Previously page with data entered when form is invalid

Tags: django, view, django-forms, django-views

Can I make my page return with the information previously entered when the form is invalid?

Views.py

```
def MyView(request):
   [...code...]
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid()
         //do something and redirect to success page
      else:
         //back to the page with the information filled in by the user (HERE IS MY PROBLEM)
```

Answer (score 0):

the line `form = MyForm(request.POST or None)` creates a `MyForm` object called `form` with request data assigned to it - its kinda like filled out form. The `is_valid()` method checks for errors in your form and adds particular errors to your `form` so this is now a filled out form with errors assigned. If you want to return this form to user you should add it to context so considering its a standard django function based view it should look like this:

```
def MyView(request):
   [...code...]
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid()
         form.save()
         return render(request, 'succes_page_template.html')
      else:
         return render(request, 'current_template.html', context = {'form': form})
```

if the `form` is invalid the next thing the user sees is same page where he filled out the form ('current_template.html') but with all the fields filled with data he/she already put it also form will have erros assigned to particular fields so you can print them. If you are new to Django I suggest getting into class based views from the start - they do the heavy lifting for you and refactoring + debugging becomes much easier. here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) cheers!